# Amazon workspaces client on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10

Is it possible to get an amazon workspaces client working on Ubuntu 23.10? On the official amazon client download page https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install it looks like they only support Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried installing "amz-workspaces" via snap following the instructions here https://snapcraft.io/install/amz-workspaces/ubuntu , but I get a "Unable to connect. The current version of your Amazon Workspaces client isn't compatible with the agent software installed on your workspace. Update to the latest version of your client, and then try to login again" error after trying to login via the "amz-workspaces" client.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get an amazon workspaces client working on Ubuntu
> 23.10?

Seems not.

> **Requirements**
>
> The WorkSpaces Linux client application requires either 64-bit Ubuntu
> 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04 (AMD64), or Ubuntu 22.04. IGEL OS is supported by the WorkSpaces Linux client.

> For the WorkSpaces Linux client version 2023.x to be able to access
> the WorkSpaces service, you must add the WorkSpaces Web Access domain
> (https://webclient.amazonworkspaces.com/) to the allowlist on the
> network from which the client is trying to access the service.

It seems that only the last 3 Ubuntu LTS versions are available for AWS Workspaces.

[AWS reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/userguide/amazon-workspaces-linux-client.html)